# Read the data only when there are three columns in R

Tags: r

I have a file where I have a bunch of data and text. I want to read the file in such a way that I only retain the lines with three coordinates.  Three coordinates refer to the lines where I have a format such as `490353.36,   3755632.81,   109.73`. In other words, I want to retain the data after surface line. The data has the x, y and z coordinates at different cross-sections.

The sample data is as follows:

```
ENDSTREAMNETWORK:

BEGIN CROSS-SECTIONS:

  CROSS-SECTION:
    STREAM ID:Sipsey Fork     
    REACH ID:Sipsey Fork     
    STATION:13.60   
    NODE NAME:                
    CUT LINE:
      490353.358391478 , 3755632.80772044 
      490254.511677942 , 3755640.28160111 
      490229.8 , 3755642.15 
      490205.088314326 , 3755644.01839947 
      490130.953109393 , 3755649.62143546 
    SURFACE LINE:
     490353.36,   3755632.81,   109.73
     490341.00,   3755633.74,   103.63
     490331.74,   3755634.44,   97.54
     490276.13,   3755638.65,   91.44
     490263.78,   3755639.58,   85.34
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490242.16,   3755641.22,   75.59
     490229.80,   3755642.15,   75.59
     490217.44,   3755643.08,   75.59
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490186.55,   3755645.42,   85.34
     490177.29,   3755646.12,   91.44
     490158.75,   3755647.52,   97.54
     490146.40,   3755648.45,   103.63
     490130.95,   3755649.62,   109.73
  END:

  CROSS-SECTION:
    STREAM ID:Sipsey Fork     
    REACH ID:Sipsey Fork     
    STATION:13.552* 
    NODE NAME:                
    CUT LINE:
      490348.236792825 , 3755554.44864345 
      490248.581497463 , 3755561.99219479 
      490223.87626427 , 3755563.8637565 
      490199.171038808 , 3755565.73531763 
      490122.732478269 , 3755571.5258566 
    SURFACE LINE:
     490348.24,   3755554.45,   109.73
     490335.78,   3755555.39,   103.68
     490332.73,   3755555.62,   101.72
     490326.44,   3755556.10,   97.65
     490321.09,   3755556.50,   96.98
     490279.74,   3755559.63,   92.42
     490270.38,   3755560.34,   91.35
     490262.42,   3755560.94,   87.53
     490258.64,   3755561.23,   85.56
     490257.92,   3755561.29,   85.22
     490253.65,   3755561.61,   82.50
     490248.58,   3755561.99,   79.27
     490248.58,   3755561.99,   79.27
     490245.75,   3755562.21,   78.40
     490243.64,   3755562.37,   77.73
     490236.08,   3755562.94,   75.58
     490223.88,   3755563.86,   75.58
     490212.36,   3755564.74,   75.58
     490209.15,   3755564.98,   76.44
     490206.21,   3755565.20,   77.24
     490200.50,   3755565.63,   78.84
     490199.17,   3755565.74,   79.26
     490199.17,   3755565.74,   79.26
     490197.66,   3755565.85,   79.78
     490193.00,   3755566.20,   81.22
     490186.72,   3755566.68,   83.20
     490182.06,   3755567.03,   84.83
     490180.06,   3755567.18,   85.47
     490170.51,   3755567.91,   91.44
     490170.23,   3755567.93,   91.52
     490151.40,   3755569.35,   97.45
     490141.55,   3755570.10,   102.06
     490138.66,   3755570.32,   103.48
     490133.49,   3755570.71,   105.53
     490122.73,   3755571.53,   109.73
  END:
```

I have thousands of lines as shown above. I only want to compile all the data with three columns separated by commas and save this as a dataframe in R.

**The sample output I require for the above dataset is as follows. The commas should also be removed**

```
     490353.36,   3755632.81,   109.73
     490341.00,   3755633.74,   103.63
     490331.74,   3755634.44,   97.54
     490276.13,   3755638.65,   91.44
     490263.78,   3755639.58,   85.34
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490242.16,   3755641.22,   75.59
     490229.80,   3755642.15,   75.59
     490217.44,   3755643.08,   75.59
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490186.55,   3755645.42,   85.34
     490177.29,   3755646.12,   91.44
     490158.75,   3755647.52,   97.54
     490146.40,   3755648.45,   103.63
     490130.95,   3755649.62,   109.73
     490348.24,   3755554.45,   109.73
     490335.78,   3755555.39,   103.68
     490332.73,   3755555.62,   101.72
     490326.44,   3755556.10,   97.65
     490321.09,   3755556.50,   96.98
     490279.74,   3755559.63,   92.42
     490270.38,   3755560.34,   91.35
     490262.42,   3755560.94,   87.53
     490258.64,   3755561.23,   85.56
     490257.92,   3755561.29,   85.22
     490253.65,   3755561.61,   82.50
     490248.58,   3755561.99,   79.27
     490248.58,   3755561.99,   79.27
     490245.75,   3755562.21,   78.40
     490243.64,   3755562.37,   77.73
     490236.08,   3755562.94,   75.58
     490223.88,   3755563.86,   75.58
     490212.36,   3755564.74,   75.58
     490209.15,   3755564.98,   76.44
     490206.21,   3755565.20,   77.24
     490200.50,   3755565.63,   78.84
     490199.17,   3755565.74,   79.26
     490199.17,   3755565.74,   79.26
     490197.66,   3755565.85,   79.78
     490193.00,   3755566.20,   81.22
     490186.72,   3755566.68,   83.20
     490182.06,   3755567.03,   84.83
     490180.06,   3755567.18,   85.47
     490170.51,   3755567.91,   91.44
     490170.23,   3755567.93,   91.52
     490151.40,   3755569.35,   97.45
     490141.55,   3755570.10,   102.06
     490138.66,   3755570.32,   103.48
     490133.49,   3755570.71,   105.53
     490122.73,   3755571.53,   109.73
```

Comment: If you are using linux or have `awk`, this one liner can help too `awk '{FS = ","} {if (NF == 3) print}' raw_text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this by first reading the text file in with `readLines`:

```
tt <- readLines("myfile.txt")
pat <- "^[ ]*(.*),(.*),(.*)[ ]*$"
tt <- gsub(pat, "\\1,\\2,\\3", grep(pat, tt, value=TRUE))
dat <- read.table(textConnection(tt), sep=",", header=FALSE)
```

---

The idea: First we read the whole file in `tt` so that we can do all required changes, filter desired lines etc. Then we need to choose which lines to keep and which ones to throw away. For that we construct a pattern *0-any amount of space followed by anything followed by a `,` followed by anything followed by a `,` followed by anything followed by 0-any amount of spaces*. This'll ensure that you get just the lines that are with 3 columns separated by `,`. So, first we use this `pat` with `grep` to filter those lines and keep only those lines that match pattern (by using `value=TRUE`). Then we use `gsub` to remove the white spaces and retain just what's in between the `,`s (not absolutely necessary I think, but it doesn't hurt to be sure). Then, we now have the data we need. All we have to do is pass it to `textConnection` and read using `read.table` as you normally would. Hope this helps.

The lines are already broken apart. Just by typing these lines one by one and looking at the output, you should be able to understand it right away though.

Comment: @Arun : Thank you so much Arun. Would you please add text to each line of code to explain what each line is doing ?

Answer (score 3):

This is so ugly I almost didn't even post it. But, it works. I read in your data like:

```
raw<-read.table(textConnection('NDSTREAMNETWORK:

BEGIN CROSS-SECTIONS:

  CROSS-SECTION:
    STREAM ID:Sipsey Fork     
    REACH ID:Sipsey Fork     
    STATION:13.60   
    NODE NAME:                
    CUT LINE:
      490353.358391478 , 3755632.80772044 
      490254.511677942 , 3755640.28160111 
      490229.8 , 3755642.15 
      490205.088314326 , 3755644.01839947 
      490130.953109393 , 3755649.62143546 
    SURFACE LINE:
     490353.36,   3755632.81,   109.73
     490341.00,   3755633.74,   103.63
     490331.74,   3755634.44,   97.54
     490276.13,   3755638.65,   91.44
     490263.78,   3755639.58,   85.34
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490242.16,   3755641.22,   75.59
     490229.80,   3755642.15,   75.59
     490217.44,   3755643.08,   75.59
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490186.55,   3755645.42,   85.34
     490177.29,   3755646.12,   91.44
     490158.75,   3755647.52,   97.54
     490146.40,   3755648.45,   103.63
     490130.95,   3755649.62,   109.73
  END:

  CROSS-SECTION:
    STREAM ID:Sipsey Fork     
    REACH ID:Sipsey Fork     
    STATION:13.552* 
    NODE NAME:                
    CUT LINE:
      490348.236792825 , 3755554.44864345 
      490248.581497463 , 3755561.99219479 
      490223.87626427 , 3755563.8637565 
      490199.171038808 , 3755565.73531763 
      490122.732478269 , 3755571.5258566 
    SURFACE LINE:
     490348.24,   3755554.45,   109.73
     490335.78,   3755555.39,   103.68
     490332.73,   3755555.62,   101.72
     490326.44,   3755556.10,   97.65
     490321.09,   3755556.50,   96.98
     490279.74,   3755559.63,   92.42
     490270.38,   3755560.34,   91.35
     490262.42,   3755560.94,   87.53
     490258.64,   3755561.23,   85.56
     490257.92,   3755561.29,   85.22
     490253.65,   3755561.61,   82.50
     490248.58,   3755561.99,   79.27
     490248.58,   3755561.99,   79.27
     490245.75,   3755562.21,   78.40
     490243.64,   3755562.37,   77.73
     490236.08,   3755562.94,   75.58
     490223.88,   3755563.86,   75.58
     490212.36,   3755564.74,   75.58
     490209.15,   3755564.98,   76.44
     490206.21,   3755565.20,   77.24
     490200.50,   3755565.63,   78.84
     490199.17,   3755565.74,   79.26
     490199.17,   3755565.74,   79.26
     490197.66,   3755565.85,   79.78
     490193.00,   3755566.20,   81.22
     490186.72,   3755566.68,   83.20
     490182.06,   3755567.03,   84.83
     490180.06,   3755567.18,   85.47
     490170.51,   3755567.91,   91.44
     490170.23,   3755567.93,   91.52
     490151.40,   3755569.35,   97.45
     490141.55,   3755570.10,   102.06
     490138.66,   3755570.32,   103.48
     490133.49,   3755570.71,   105.53
     490122.73,   3755571.53,   109.73
  END:'),sep='\n',stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then I wrangle it into a `data.frame`

```
vec<-unlist(raw)

start<-grep('SURFACE LINE:',vec)+1
end<-grep('END:',vec)-1

data<-do.call(rbind,
lapply(seq_along(start), 
  function(x) read.table(textConnection(vec[start[x]:end[x]])))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the shortest but the more easier to understand for me

```
raw_text <- "ENDSTREAMNETWORK:

BEGIN CROSS-SECTIONS:

  CROSS-SECTION:
    STREAM ID:Sipsey Fork     
    REACH ID:Sipsey Fork     
    STATION:13.60   
    NODE NAME:                
    CUT LINE:
      490353.358391478 , 3755632.80772044 
      490254.511677942 , 3755640.28160111 
      490229.8 , 3755642.15 
      490205.088314326 , 3755644.01839947 
      490130.953109393 , 3755649.62143546 
    SURFACE LINE:
     490353.36,   3755632.81,   109.73
     490341.00,   3755633.74,   103.63
     490331.74,   3755634.44,   97.54
     490276.13,   3755638.65,   91.44
     490263.78,   3755639.58,   85.34
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490254.51,   3755640.28,   79.25
     490242.16,   3755641.22,   75.59
     490229.80,   3755642.15,   75.59
     490217.44,   3755643.08,   75.59
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490205.09,   3755644.02,   79.25
     490186.55,   3755645.42,   85.34
     490177.29,   3755646.12,   91.44
     490158.75,   3755647.52,   97.54
     490146.40,   3755648.45,   103.63
     490130.95,   3755649.62,   109.73
  END:"
```

Here are the steps

```
## read the data
raw_data <- readLines(textConnection(raw_text))

## split by ","
split_list <- strsplit(raw_data, ",")

## check for 3 columns
data <- split_list[sapply(split_list, length) == 3]

## remove space and ","
data <- lapply(data, function(x) gsub("\\s+|\\,", "", x))

## bind the data 
do.call("rbind", data)


##       [,1]        [,2]         [,3]    
##  [1,] "490353.36" "3755632.81" "109.73"
##  [2,] "490341.00" "3755633.74" "103.63"
##  [3,] "490331.74" "3755634.44" "97.54" 
##  [4,] "490276.13" "3755638.65" "91.44" 
##  [5,] "490263.78" "3755639.58" "85.34" 
##  [6,] "490254.51" "3755640.28" "79.25" 
##  [7,] "490254.51" "3755640.28" "79.25" 
##  [8,] "490242.16" "3755641.22" "75.59" 
##  [9,] "490229.80" "3755642.15" "75.59" 
## [10,] "490217.44" "3755643.08" "75.59" 
## [11,] "490205.09" "3755644.02" "79.25" 
## [12,] "490205.09" "3755644.02" "79.25" 
## [13,] "490186.55" "3755645.42" "85.34" 
## [14,] "490177.29" "3755646.12" "91.44" 
## [15,] "490158.75" "3755647.52" "97.54" 
## [16,] "490146.40" "3755648.45" "103.63"
## [17,] "490130.95" "3755649.62" "109.73"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest yet another approach. As @dickoa pointed out, if you are a linux or mac user, you can use a third party program like `awk` or `egrep` to do the filtering for you. There is no need to do that filtering manually outside of R, you can do it with a single `system` call. Both of these work:

With `awk` as suggested by @dickoa:

```
read.table(text = system("awk '{FS = \",\"} {if (NF == 3) print}' test.txt",
                         intern = TRUE),
           sep = ',')
```

With `egrep`:

```
read.table(text = system("egrep '^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$' test.txt", intern = TRUE),
           sep = ',')
```

This has the advantage that it does not force R to read all the data into memory, which could make a difference if you were reading from very large files. It is also shorter than the other suggested answers.